# Is tetration a transcendental function?

Tags: tetration, transcendental-equations, differential-algebra

Is tetration a transcendental function?

If so are there any papers with a proof?

I suspect that it is because I have not seen any algebraic situations where tetration is the answer and the fact that it has little active research.

For those unaware of tetration:
$${}^na=\underbrace{a^{a^{a^{.^{.^{.^a}}}}}}_{n \text{ times}}$$
and assuming it's extension to $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$.

Comment: If Wikipedia's definition of "transcendental function" is to be believed (“A transcendental function is a function that does not satisfy a polynomial equation whose coefficients are themselves polynomials”) then the answer is certainly yes, because ${}^na$ is easily seen to exceed any polynomial in $a$ and $n$.

Comment: Hint : No algebraic function has superexponenetial growth rate.

Comment: Even $\exp(x)$ is a transcendental function, since the Taylor series is infinite; this is also true for all other exponential bases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Already $x^x$ grows faster than any algebraic function (which is asymptotic to $x^q$ for $\,q\in \Bbb Q).$ And they grow even faster as you tetrate $f \mapsto x^f.\,$ Hence for $\,n>1,\,$ they are  transcendental, i.e. not algebraic functions.